# Datetime is changed in wcf service c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a record in my database as you can see :

[image]

My service return this like this :

```
Id  142
SubmitDatetime  "/Date(1509309000000+0330)/"
```

When i deserialize the above datetime .the datetime is changed to 2017/10/29.why ?

The service time zone is `Tehran 3:30`

Comment: is the machine caluclating it not in a timezone with more than 3.5 hours plus on gmt? if its say france at +1 ...... then thats like 10:30pm on the 29th oct

Comment: @MartinBackasch yes both of them are utc:tehran 3:30

Comment: @BugFinder yes ,but both of them are utc:tehran 3:30

Comment: Is that `SubmitDatetime` field in your database intending to reflect the local time in Tehran?  If so, the corresponding UTC time is `2017-10-29 20:30:00`. Usually it is be better to store the UTC time directly, and convert where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is in a timezone that is not the same as your service data. So the time gets calculated for the timezone you are in and voila: different time and potentially different day if the difference is large enough.

Comment: Both of them are utc tehran 3:30

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Your problems let me believe that this is not the case. Considering daylights savings time was last week for Iran, it's either timezones... or magic gnomes :)